# ASP.NET MVC 3 - How is this boolean value working in the controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm looking at a tutorial for asp.net mvc here on the asp site:  http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-basic-crud-functionality-with-the-entity-framework-in-asp-net-mvc-application

There is a method in the controller that has me confused:

```
//
        // GET: /Student/Delete/5

        public ActionResult Delete(int id, bool? saveChangesError)
        {
            if (saveChangesError.GetValueOrDefault())
            {
                ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Unable to save changes.  Try again, and if the problem persists contact your system administrator.";
            }
            return View(db.Students.Find(id));
        }
```

I'm seeing that a bool is created called 'saveChangesError', but in the if statement, there is a method being called on the boolean called 'GetValueOrDefault()'

What exactly is going on in this scenario?  I'm assuming that GetValueOrDefault() must be a method of all boolean types?  I looked this up in the .NET documentation and found this definition:

> The value of the Value property if the HasValue property is true;
>   otherwise, the default value of the current Nullable(Of T) object. The
>   type of the default value is the type argument of the current
>   Nullable(Of T) object, and the value of the default value consists
>   solely of binary zeroes.

I'm having trouble connecting this definition with what is going on the the .net mvc app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`GetValueOrDefault()` isn't part of the `bool`, [it's part of `Nullable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx).  The key here is the syntax where the `bool` is declared in the function header:

```
public ActionResult Delete(int id, bool? saveChangesError)
```

The question mark is a C# language construct which indicates that this isn't *really* a `bool`, but is a `Nullable<bool>`.  Value types, of which `bool` is one, can't be `null`.  But sometimes it would be useful if they *could*.  So the `Nullable<T>` struct exists to serve that purpose.

`GetValueOrDefault()` is a method on that struct which will return the value of the `bool` or the default value for a `bool` ([which is `false`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8f5xwh7.aspx)) if no value is specified.

Comment: Thank you, lots of good answers but this is most helpful to me.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72cec0e0.aspx) states that `GetValueOrDefault()` "Retrieves the value of the current `Nullable(Of T)` object, or the object's default value." `Nullable(Of T)` in this case is `saveChangesError`.

If there has been an error in saving changes to the database (in this case, deleting a student), then `saveChangesError.GetValueOrDefault()` will return true and the if statement will process its contents.

Comment: default values, in case the OP doesn't know, are what the value is when you declare something without initializing it. So the default value of bools is false, of ints is 0, of objects null, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the definition of the parameter `bool? saveChangesError` The '?' means the bool type is nullable. It can be `True` | `False` | `Null`.

Because it now has three values, You can't simply check for `true` | `false`. You must check for null as well.

`GetValueOrDefault()` is added to nullable types that does exactly what the method describes. If the parameter has a value, it will return that, if it doesn't it returns the default value (in this case it is **false**).

So, to break the if statement out, would be something like

```
if (saveChangesError.HasValue && saveChangesError == true)
{
    //...
}
```

Using the method just makes it more concise.

Answer (score 1):

Nullable objects all implement an overloaded method called GetValueOrDefault:
Returns the value of the nullable object if it has been assigned one, or a default value.

Answer (score 1):

```
bool? saveChangesError
```

is a nullable boolean datatype. It has three possible value:
1) true
2) false
3) null

The GetValueOrDefault() will return either true or false if the value is set, or null when its not set. In the mention scenario, if the value is true

```
if (saveChangesError.GetValueOrDefault())
```

An error has occured. Hope this helps

Comment: GetValueOrDefault() will not return null for bools.

Comment: @bhamlin sorry bout that i was over eager, you can only set the bool to null, which defaults to false with the GetValueOrDefault() method.